# mysql create table ... what am i doing wrong

Tags: mysql, create-table

```
  CREATE TABLE 'behandelingen' (
  'behandeling_id' int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  'behandeling' varchar(35) NOT NULL default '',
  'kosten' float NOT NULL default '0',
  'bank_reknr' varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  ('behandeling_id'),
  UNIQUE KEY 'behandeling' ('behandeling')
);
```

Trying to import a database / tables to a my local server using phpmyadmin. I keep coming up with the following error

> > ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> >
> > near ''behandelingen' (   'behandeling_id' int(10) NOT NULL
> >     auto_increment,   'behan' at line 1
> >     Static analysis:
>
> 4 errors were found during analysis.
>
> ```
> A symbol name was expected! (near "'behandeling_id'" at position 34)
> At least one column definition was expected. (near "'behandeling_id'" at position 34)
> Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 55)
> Unrecognized statement type. (near "NOT NULL" at position 59)
> ```

can some one shed some light on it ... I am using Server version: 5.7.14 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks instead of single quotes on the table name and column names. See below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `behandelingen` (
    `behandeling_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `behandeling` varchar(35) NOT NULL default '',
    `kosten` float NOT NULL default '0',
    `bank_reknr` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
    PRIMARY KEY  (`behandeling_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `behandeling` (`behandeling`)
);
```

Comment: so the only issue was i should remove the single quotes ???? ... it does work... but this was never an issue ...any ideas why the quotes are an issue all of a sudden ?

Comment: you should use ` , not '  :-)

Comment: I chose this ..as it was the first answer

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TABLE behandelingen (   behandeling_id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,   behandeling varchar(35) NOT NULL default 'default' ,   kosten float NOT NULL default 0,   bank_reknr varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'default' ,  PRIMARY KEY  (behandeling_id),   UNIQUE KEY behandeling (behandeling) );

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but I think that you shouldn't be using single quotes to define the name of the column: e.g.

CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255) 
);